# How to find the column name which has max value by comparing multiple column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need the column name for which there are same value in many columns, I need to pick the last max value column name in another column .
for example

```
   KEY    A    B    C    D    E   F
0    1  100  100  100  100   50  50
1    2  200  200  200   50  200  50
```

Output should be like

```
   KEY    A    B    C    D    E   F  G
0    1  100  100  100  100   50  50  D
1    2  200  200  200   50  200  50  E
```

Please help me to get the result. I have tried using `.idxmax(axis=1)` which is pulling the first occurrence and giving me the first column name.

I have a data frame like df

```
SITE    Counter KEY Full_name   B   C   D   E   F
LO  ALA LO_ALA  ALPHA   100 100 100 50  50
LO  BLA LO_BLA  BALPA   200 200 50  200 50
LO  ALA LO_ALA  ALPHA   1000    1000    1000    100 1000
LO  BLA LO_BLA  BALPA   2000    2000    100 2000    1000
```

I run the query

```
df['G'] = df[["B","C","D","E","F"]].values.max(1)
df = df.sort_values(['MAX_LIMIT'], ascending=[0])
df = df.drop_duplicates(['KEY'], keep='first')
```

after above code, I get one value for each KEY, then I need is that the column name which is matching to the last

Next I run `df['H'] =df[["B","C","D","E","F"]].idxmax(axis =1)`

I need the output as

```
SITE    Counter KEY Full_name G     H
LO  ALA LO_ALA  ALPHA   1000    F   
LO  BLA LO_BLA  BALPA   2000    E
```

BUT THE OUTPUT I AM GETTING IS

```
SITE    Counter KEY Full_name G     H
LO  ALA LO_ALA  ALPHA   1000    B   
LO  BLA LO_BLA  BALPA   2000    B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the columns and find `idxmax`:

```
df.set_index('KEY', inplace=True)
df[df.columns[::-1]].idxmax(axis=1)

KEY
1    D
2    E
dtype: object
```

**EDIT :** Change the query like:

```
df['G'] = df[["B","C","D","E","F"]].values.max(1)
df = df.drop_duplicates(['KEY'], keep='last')
df['H'] = df[df.columns[4:-1][::-1]].idxmax(axis=1)

print(df)
  SITE Counter     KEY Full_name     B     C     D     E     F     G  H
2   LO     ALA  LO_ALA     ALPHA  1000  1000  1000   100  1000  1000  F
3   LO     BLA  LO_BLA     BALPA  2000  2000   100  2000  1000  2000  E
```

Comment: Yeah, nice one..+1 :)

Comment: I tried , am getting wrote as could not convert string to float : MDBG

Comment: Here is the code ,
df['MAX_LIMIT_BUCKET']= df2[["Input CCY - Call Bucket","Input CCY - TDY Bucket","Input CCY - TOM Bucket","Input CCY - TDY Bucket", "Input CCY - TOM Bucket",
       "Input CCY - SPT Bucket", "Input CCY - SPT-1M bucket",
       "Input CCY - 1-3M Bucket", "Input CCY - 3-6M Bucket",
       "Input CCY - 6-1Y Bucket", "Input CCY - 1-3Y Bucket",
       "Input CCY - 3-5Y Bucket", "Input CCY - 5-7Y Bucket",
       "Input CCY - 7-10Y Bucket", "Input CCY - 10-15Y Bucket",
       "Input CCY - 15Y+ Bucket"]].idxmax(axis=1)

Comment: @Karthike You cannot convert a string to float. Did it work for you?

Comment: @sandeep : No it didn't work for me, I am getting error for it, above is the actual code written to pull the required result but I am getting the first occurrence which is not I need.

Comment: @Karthike Could you show an example in the question for which it not working?

Comment: @SandeepKadapa : I have added the new example for my query  Please excuse me for the format, I am not getting the table format in here